# Converting RootObject properties to Double causes crash

Tags: c#, xamarin

When I try to convert my properties in RootObject to Double it causes my app to crash. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

my RootObject:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Double wantedDegree
    {
        get
        {
            return wantedDegree;
        }
        set
        {
            wantedDegree = Convert.ToDouble(value);
        }
    }
    public Double currentDegree
    {
        get
        {
            return currentDegree;
        }
        set
        {
            currentDegree = Convert.ToDouble(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Calling the RootObject:

```
var Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(content);
currentDegree.Text = String.Format("{0:F1}°", Items.currentDegree);
degreeControls.Value = Items.wantedDegree;
```

My JSON Array (content):

```
{
"wantedDegree": 22,
"currentDegree": 20
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("wantedDegree")]
    public Double WantedDegree { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("currentDegree")]
    public Double CurrentDegree { get; set; }
}
```

Then just use:

```
var Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(content);
```

Comment: Yes thank you this worked perfectly! Also after reading the docs about it it makes perfect sense.